# SQL query for CosmosDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Please help me write SQL query for CosmosDB (C#).
I have two documents in the single container with two common values (Value 1 and Value 3).

```
Document 1
{
  "id": "6b421d58-57d8-4d8e-941d-4f441a9a2439",
  "item": {
  "Value1": "d27d31b6-0632-4f9e-bec7-ede0e12fbe78",
  "Value2": "00000000-0632-4f9e-bec7-ede0e12fbe78"
  }
}

Document 2
{
  "id": "111111-57d8-4d8e-941d-4f441a9a2439",
  "item": {
  "Value3": "d27d31b6-0632-4f9e-bec7-ede0e12fbe78"
  }
}
```

How can I get Value2 from Document 1 by Id of Document 2?
Value 1 and Value 3 are the same.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Have you read how cosmosDB SQL is not the same SQL as in relational DB? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-getting-started

Comment: @ImrePühvel maybe it's possible with subquery?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not possible to query the value from one document using a filter predicate for another.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problems with Azure firewall, according to this [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403829/unable-to-deploy-python-http-trigger-function-to-f.html)